PyPDF2: When I combine pdf files some files are duplicated and others are missing
Sometimes when I try to combine Pdf files, a page would be duplicated where the next page
is supposed to be.
Here is the code I use to combine the pdf files.
    pdfFiles = []
    for filename in os.listdir(self.source):
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            pdfFiles.append(os.path.join(self.source,filename))


    pdfFiles.sort(key = str.lower)

    pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
    for filename in pdfFiles:
        #print(filename)
        pdfFileObj = open(filename,'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdfFileObj)
        #for pageNum in range(0, pdfReader.numPages):
        for pageNum in range(len(pdfReader.pages)):
            #pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
            pageObj = pdfReader.pages[pageNum]
            pdfWriter.add_page(pageObj)
            pdfFileObj.close()

    fileout = CombineName
    #print(fileout)
    pdfOutput = open(self.destination + fileout,'wb')
    pdfWriter.write(pdfOutput)
    pdfOutput.close()

The number pages are correct but some pages are duplicated and the other page is missing.

pdfFileObj.close() is inside the for loop that goes through each page of the PDF, which should not happen because you're still using the pdfFileObj to read the page
I think you'll want to close it as well after you're done processing
Give this a try
pdfFiles = []
for filename in os.listdir(self.source):
    if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
        pdfFiles.append(os.path.join(self.source, filename))

pdfFiles.sort(key=str.lower)

pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
for filename in pdfFiles:
    pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdfFileObj)
    for pageNum in range(len(pdfReader.pages)):
        pageObj = pdfReader.pages[pageNum]
        pdfWriter.add_page(pageObj)
    pdfFileObj.close()  # Move this line outside the inner loop

fileout = CombineName
pdfOutput = open(self.destination + fileout, 'wb')
pdfWriter.write(pdfOutput)
pdfOutput.close()

